# Vector-valued variational inequality in $L^2(\Omega)^n$ with test functions $\nabla v$, $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and assume $\mathbf{u} \in L^2(\Omega)^n$ satisfies $\int_\Omega \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla v \, dx = 0$ for all $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. Can I conclude $\mathbf{u} = 0$?

The usual trick of choosing $\nabla v = \mathbf{u}$ and using the properties of the norm does not work here because we do not know whether such a $v$ exists. Also arguments about limiting the support of $\nabla v$ to regions where $\mathbf{u}$ is non-zero seem dubious because $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ implies we cannot choose "simple" $v$, e.g. such that $\nabla v$ is zero in all components except one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can't. Assume $\mathbf{u} \in H^1(\Omega)^n \supset L^2(\Omega)^n$. Then, the variational equality is equivalent to $\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \, v \, dx = 0$ for all $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, so $\mathbf{u}$ only needs to be divergence free, not zero.